# Does ARM require provisioning a resource both within the parent resource as well as outside a parent resource?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

A good example is a subnet declaration within a vnet resource. I can add a subnet to a vnet via this ARM syntax

```
//vnet declaration with subnet declaration in subnets arrary
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
    "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
    "name": "vnetName",
    ...
    "properties": {
      "subnets": [
         "name": "subnetName",
         "properties": {
           ...
         }
      ],
    }            
}
```

I can also add it outside of the vnet declaration like this:

```
//vnet declaration w/out subnet
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
    "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
    "name": "vnetName",
    ...
    "properties": {
      ...
    }            
}


//separate subnet declaration as specific type outside of vnet declaration, but dependsOn vnet
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
  "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
  "name": "subnetName",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'vnetName')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
      ...
    }
}
```

A quick google on this landed me on this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/child-resource-name-type?tabs=json) page which shows you how to do it by nesting a resources array within the parent resource, not utilizing the subnets array.

I'd like to know what's required b/c if the same subnet needs to be declared both within the vnet declaration as well as outside the vnet declaration as its own type, that adds a lot of verbosity to the ARM template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Both are not required the external declaration is there to help with avoiding [circular dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/define-resource-dependency#circular-dependencies) and give control on deploy order.

In your example adding the subnet definitions within the VNet declaration will always be okay as you wouldn't create a [circular dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/define-resource-dependency#circular-dependencies).

However let's say we have a Key Vault and a web app that references secrets in that vault.

Firstly we create the Key Vault with the needed secrets. However with this we also need the access policy setup to allow the app service to reference the secrets.
If we were to try and do this internally then it would be trying to reference an app service that doesn't exist.

To fix this we use an external declaration for the access policy which is dependent on both the Key Vault and App service. This allows both to be created and then access to be granted; when all the Ids have been generated.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/define-resource-dependency) article from Microsoft explains all of this in more detail.

Comment: thanks for the reply! In your first sentence, you say "TL;DR Both are not required the is there to help with avoiding circular dependencies and give control on deploy order.", but I think you left a word out between "the" and "is there"... "the WHAT is there"? Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMcCarthy I have fixed it. Clearly was to late at night to be writing answers

Answer (score 1):

@blockingHD is correct - and there's more nuance to this as well.

In the case of a vnet - a subnet property is always "evaulated" and if you don't provide it, it will be treated as if you supplied an empty array.  That has the effect of removing your subnets if they exist.  When not empty they are replaced with the contents of the property.

In the case of KeyVault, the accessPolicies property is required, you can't omit it from the template.  If you supply it (empty or not) it replaces the accessPolicies on the vault -- the same in both cases since the template is declarative.

What this all means is that you need to be aware of out-of-band changes, like adding an access policy for a managed identity, and whether your [initial] declarations will overwrite them when deployed again.

For both subnets and accessPolicies the child resources are good for "additive" scenarios but you need to be aware of when the parent resource (vault or vnet) will be deployed without those additions as if they are not included, will be lost.

That help?

Comment: "That has the effect of removing your subnets if they exist." Yikes. I did NOT know this. Thank you so much for the info. Are all child arrays of parent resources evaluated in the same manner, or is this something specific to resources like vnets and vaults?

Comment: Well in general, specifying an empty array will declare an empty array - whether there's a child resource or not.  So you could see it in other cases...  But the problem you ran into most often occurs when properties are modeled as both a property and a child.  (vaults and vnets)